# ASP.NET Core 6 razor page routing default page route within different Areas

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, routes

In .NET 6 Razor pages, when I use the following code to map page routes while the pages are in the default pages folder or sub-folder of it, it works perfectly like that:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {       
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Account/login", "login");
    }
    ).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

where the page structure is `Pages/Account/*.*`

However, when I try to map page routes of a page under an area that is not under the default pages folder it does not work as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {       
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/identity/Account/login", "login");
    }
    ).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

given that, `/identity/Account/login` is under the directory `/Areas/identity/pages/Account/login` and the default `Pages` folder is pages in the same level as areas folder. i.e. both the areas and main pages folder (pages) are direct children of the main folder.

Notes:

1. When I access `http://localhost/identity/Account/login` - it works well
2. When I add attribute routing in the display template login in the to add - page `/` it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the pages under an areas, you can use the `AddAreaPageRoute` method to add the page Convention:

[image]

You can check the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Index", "homeindex");
        options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Manage","/Admin/AdminIndex", "login");
    }
    );
```

The result is like this:

[image]

More detail information, see [Razor Pages Routing](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes) and [Razor Pages route and app conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as you thankfully illustrated. Thanks for the well-illustrated answer. My issue was that I did not know about AddAreaPageRoute.